# Django: create a separate set of models in in-memory SQLite DB on the flight

Tags: python, django, sqlite

What I'm trying to do:

I have a general huge set of models in my Django (v2.3.3) application in PostgreSQL DB, but now for a specific task I need to create a rather complicated aggregation of DB objects. And it would be much easier to work with them if I could only in that thread/process that handles this specific web-request create an in-memory SQLite DB, define a new set of model-classes there (without foreign keys to the global set of models of course), create some objects in that DB, do my calculations and kill that DB upon the response serving. For consistency I would like to use Django models for this small DB as well.

Is this possible? Or do you have some better ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've ended up with SQLAlchemy + in-memory SQLite solution:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, backref

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class Node(Base):
    """A node entity in sankey diagram."""
    __tablename__ = 'node'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)  # unique - might include parts from event.extra_data
    event = Column(String)  # not unique - totally equeals to event.event

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```